# using single and double quotes in php form

Tags: php, html

I ran into this code:

```
function input_text($elem, $val) {
  print '<input type = "test" name="' . $elem .'" val="';
  print htmlentities($val[elem]) . '"/>';
```

I m confused about the code: `name="' . $elem .'" val="';
print htmlentities($val[elem]) . '"/>'`

1) why put single quotes and dot inside double quotes around $elem? Can i just use double quotes like name="$elem".

2) what is the meaning of these code: `val="';
print htmlentities($val[elem]) . '"/>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Since the string being printed is surrounded with single quotes, variables are not expanded inside it; variables are only expanded inside double-quoted strings. So concatenation is necessary. If you change it to use double quotes, you could do variable interpolation:

```
print "<input type='test' name='$elem' val='";
```

2) There's no special meaning to it. The programmer simply chose to split up the commands to print this piece of HTML into two PHP `print` statements. So first he prints `val="`, then he prints `htmlentities($val[elem]) . "">>'`

The function could be rewritten as:

```
function input_text($elem, $val) {
    print "<input type='test' name='$elem' val='" . htmlentities($val[elem]) . "'/>";
}
```

You have to use concatenation around `htmlentities()` -- only variables can be interpolated into strings, not function calls. However, you could assign the value to a variable first if you want:

```
function input_text($elem, $val) {
    $valent = htmlentities($val[elem]);
    print "<input type='test' name='$elem' val='$valent'/>";
}
```

BTW, `$val[elem]` looks like a typo, it probably should be `$val[$elem]`.

Comment: can i just use name="$elem" instead?

Comment: Yes, you can do that if you prefer.

Comment: thanks! for the question 2, can i just write:val="htmlentities($val[elem]) "/>';

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong in my earlier answer. You can't do variable interpolation like I showed, because interpolation only happens inside double quotes, not inside single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes in this case denote a string in PHP.

```
$var = 'This is a String';
```

The reason they are used in conjunction with the double quotes is because the double quotes must be printed to get the correct HTML output of

```
<input type="test" name="someName" val="someValue" />
```

The `.` operator in PHP is the concatenation operator meaning combine 2 strings into 1.

```
$var = 'This' . ' and that'; //Evaluates to 'This and that'
```

Comment: so in the expression: name="' . $elem .'", the concatenation combine the ' and $elem